# PHP exit (or die) doesn't work properly

Tags: php, exit, die

I'm trying to stop a php script using exit (or die). The problem is that after executing exit the page keeps loading and loading (and never finish) instead of stopping the script with the error message. Here is my code:

```
if($_POST["user"] == $user["email"] AND password_verify($pw, $user["password"]))
    echo "<script> alert('Successful')</script>";
else {
    echo "<script> alert('Error. Please try again.'); </script>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: The `{}` at `if` are missing.

Comment: @AjAX. No, it's a one line conditional.

Comment: Are you sure you're reaching your else statement?

Comment: What happens if you actually input the correct login details?
Does your script not hang before it reaches the exit part?

Comment: Do you see `Error. Please try again.`?

Comment: @user3783243 A one line conditional works. But — not — with `else`!

Comment: @AjAX. Yes, it does https://3v4l.org/hlZK0!

Comment: Have you defined your $pw? Try $_POST["pw"]. Check your if condition again

Comment: You need to tell us if you see the error message.

Comment: @user3783243 No I can't see the message. The page keeps just loading.

Comment: @Thijn Everything works fine when I enter the correct login information.

Comment: Copy pasting that exact code above, I get a browser alert of "Error. Please try again." (along with some undefined Notices obviously)... so, cannot reproduce. You either have not supplied the code that is causing you troubles, or something else is going on.

Comment: Does it work if you use an unknown email address? If so, and the problem is only with an incorrect password, then the issue is with the `password_verify()` function and how it reacts when the password is incorrect. Where are you setting the `$pw` variable? Also, how are you setting the `$user[]` array before login?

Comment: The login part works fine. The problem is exit. The issue with the loading page seems to happen everywhere as soon as I run exit.

Comment: Is this inside a `while` or a function? We need more information to help. Use `error_log` on each condition so you can see if you are entering an infinite loop.

Comment: You have reloading code somewhere that's not included in the above posted code.